# Is it possible to safely unmount /home partition to resize it using GParted in Ubuntu

Tags: gparted

My system's partitions look like this, I don't have a swap area, but I have enough extra space in my /home for one, how can I, safely, take some of that and turn it into a swap partition ? This is a physical installation not a virtual system.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGYwC.png)

I haven't unmounted any partitions yet, I am asking if that could be done safely, and if that would make me able to then resize the unmounted partition to extract some free space that could hopefully be used as swap space.

Comment: Re-partitioning a disk that is in use is usually not a good idea. Even though there are ways to do it, there is good chance that you will lose your data. Please make a backup of your disk and then modify the partitions. Remember lost data will cost you far more time and money than a backup disk.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using. Recent versions use a swap file and do not need a swap partition unless you have special requirements. Use an Ubuntu ostracisation USB and the **Try Ubuntu** option.